# Issues while viewing Firebase Cloud Messaging registration token in a browser(web)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use FCM for sending notifications on a web-app. I have created a project on firebase and I have the VAPID key. The difficult part is that I've been trying to implement it on the client side and view the registration token in the browser. Here is the code:

//index.html

```html
<html>
  <body> <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    
    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
         https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    
    <script>
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "*******",
        authDomain: "myproject.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://myproject.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "myproject",
        storageBucket: "myproject.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
        appId: "1:xxxxx",
        measurementId: "xxxx"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      firebase.analytics();
      const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    
      // Get registration token. Initially this makes a network call, once retrieved
    // subsequent calls to getToken will return from cache.
    messaging.getToken({vapidKey: 'xxxx'}).then((currentToken) => {
      if (currentToken) {
        console.log(currentToken);
        sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
        updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
      } else {
        // Show permission request.
        console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
        // Show permission UI.
        updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
        setTokenSentToServer(false);
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
      showToken('Error retrieving registration token. ', err);
      setTokenSentToServer(false);
    });
    </script>
   
    </body> 
    </html>
```

This is exactly what I found in the official documentation. I also added a firebase-messaging-sw.js file in the root directory.

//firebase-messaging-sw.js

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-messaging.js');

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "*****",
    authDomain: "myproject.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myproject.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "myproject",
    storageBucket: "myproject.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
    appId: "1:xxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxx"
  };

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging=firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    console.log(payload);
    const notification=JSON.parse(payload);
    const notificationOption={
        body:notification.body,
        icon:notification.icon
    };
    return self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title,notificationOption);
});
```

The code is not working and I cannot view the registration token. Any help would be highly appreciated!